# Passing arguments to functions invoked via a keymap?

Tags: keymap, interactive, arguments

Is it possible to have multiple keymap entries set up to call the same interactive function, but with different arguments associated with each mapping?

For example, suppose I have this function ...

```lisp
    (defun interactive-func (&optional arg) ;; or perhaps another arg specification
      (interactive) ;; or perhaps with one or more parameters passed
      (message "arg=%s" arg)
      (sit-for 1)
      )

... and suppose I have a keymap defined something like the following:

    (let ((map (make-keymap)))
      (suppress-keymap map)
      (define-key map "a" 'interactive-func) ;; with "abcdefg" as the argument
      (define-key map "b" 'interactive-func) ;; with "x y z" as the argument
      (define-key map "c" 'interactive-func) ;; with (list "1" "2" "3") as the argument
      ;;; etc. ;;;
      )
```

Is something like this possible? Or do I have to always use different functions with different key mappings if I want all of them to trigger different behaviors?

Comment: Dynamically providing interactive argument values is often taken care of by the `interactive` spec of the command.  Remember that you can use `(interactive FORM)` where FORM is any lisp expression which *returns a list of arguments*.  `(interactive (list ...))` is common, but you can do anything.  So if your command can figure out the arguments it needs from other context, you could just do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried:

```el
(defun interactive-func (&rest args)
  (message "%s" args))
  
(defvar my-keymap (make-keymap) 
  "Keymap")

(define-key my-keymap (kbd "C-c a") (lambda () (interactive)
                      (interactive-func "a")))

(define-key my-keymap (kbd "C-c b") (lambda () (interactive)
                      (interactive-func "a" "b")))

(define-key my-keymap (kbd "C-c c") (lambda ()  (interactive)
                      (interactive-func (list "a" "b" "c"))))

(use-local-map my-keymap)
```

I don't understand how you would define your `local-map`.

Comment: I didn't realize that I could define the keymap action with a lambda. I copied and pasted similar code (without using `'interactive-func`) from a portion of a much longer emacs module, and then I changed the actions to `'interactive-func` for my question here. That's why the keymap is shown as  being defined in the `let` clause ... which I realize isn't going to be available to the caller in the example I gave. But I wasn't worried about the keymap definition itself, only about the action definitions, and your response provided the answer that I've been looking for. Thank you very much!